# Session value will change after a little time automatically

Tags: php, session

I'm really wonder about a so confusing problem. I have a session that has a URL as value :

```
$_SESSION['url'] => 'http://www.domain.com/path/';
```

`path/` has been rewritten and is not a real directory. Session is set in `page1.php` and there is link to `page2.php`. When i click on the link and go to `page2.php`, If i do it so fast after that `page1.php` is loaded so `$_SESSION['url']` has correct value.

But when i stay 10 seconds and then click on the link and go to `page2.php`, Or even stay for 10 seconds and then refresh it, Session value will changed automatically to `404.shtml`;

I mean, It's value will changed to `http://www.domain.com/404.shtml`.
Please note that this happen just for values which are URL and other values are correct.

I'm really confused that what is happening here ? Has any body experienced this situation ?

**edit**
page1.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] => 'http://www.domain.com/path/';
```

page2.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['url']; // Output is 'http://www.domain.com/404.shtml'
```

Comment: are u using the session_start option

Comment: @Vineet1982 Nothing should return if session had not been started !

Comment: @AspiringAqib, So What ?

Comment: then not starting the session again on second page, If possible provide the code of both files

Comment: It redirects to 404.shtml automatically because the file you were accessing was not found there.

Comment: @AspiringAqib A value in session redirects ? That's only a string. How it could be redirect ? I'm not sure if i understand you !

Comment: I assume that you are setting the value in the session from somewhere else also. There is no reason due to which a value in session changes by itself.

Comment: @Omid maybe your session expires and the value becomes null. Now, that string does not remain valid path and when you click link, it redirects 404.shtml of your server. Can you add your full code?

Comment: @AspiringAqib So it should return `null` not a URL with `404.shtml` at end. Right ?

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul Yes, I was doing that, But for debugging i set it manually now. The same result.

Comment: Something is changing your URL, are you using a framework of some sort?

Comment: I think you must be doing something else in the page as such it would work if that are the full codes

Comment: @Husman I'm using a costume framework written by myself, I have tested all things may change it's value All last week. Nothing. What is wondering is that is a simple string value. If something has changed it, all value should change. Just changing `path/` to `404.shtml` is confusing.

Comment: @Husman I'm completely sure that i don't have any code to change it's value to `404.shtml`.

Comment: Odd, try changing the url session variable to not have the 'http://' part, as something is responsible for modifying URL's. If it is a string without the http:// maybe it wont change its value.

Comment: @Husman I have tested all ways last 10 days. Regardless having `path/` or `path`, While it's a rewritted URL it will changed !!! One another wondering thing is that it's happening on Online host (Linux) and i have no problem on localhost (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Checklist of things to do:

1. Are there any libraries/includes that access the $_SESSION['url'] variable? disable/un-include them.
2. Do any other variables get changed in the session?
3. Try renaming the variable, from $_SESSION['url'] to $_SESSION['test']

Comment: I have tested #2 and #3 before and about #2 should say just URLs will get changed. Have to give a try to #1

Comment: I would just create 2 new pages, without any includes, and just have the session variables in the first and echo it out in the second. Then keep adding your includes, and testing to see which one breaks it.